# Refactor linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have a linq expression that I've been playing with in LINQPad and I would like to refactor the expression to replace all the tests for `idx == -1` with a single test. The input data for this is the result of a free text search on a database used for caching Active Directory info. The search returns a list of display names and associated summary data from the matching database rows. I want to extract from that list the display name and the matching Active Directory entry. Sometimes the match will only occur on the display name so there may be no further context. In the example below, the string "Sausage" is intended to be the search term that returned the two items in the *matches* array. Clearly this wouldn't be the case for a real search because there is no match for *Sausage* in the second array item.

```
var matches = new [] 
{
    new { displayName = "Sausage Roll", summary = "|Title: Network Coordinator|Location: Best Avoided|Department: Coordination|Email: Sausage.Roll@somewhere.com|" },
    new { displayName = "Hamburger Pattie",  summary = "|Title: Network Development Engineer|Location: |Department: Planning|Email: Hamburger.Pattie@somewhere.com|" },
};

var context = (from match in matches
                let summary = match.summary
                let idx = summary.IndexOf("Sausage")
                let start = idx == -1 ? 0 : summary.LastIndexOf('|', idx) + 1
                let stop = idx == -1 ? 0 : summary.IndexOf('|', idx)
                let ctx = idx == -1 ? "" : string.Format("...{0}...", summary.Substring(start, stop - start))
                select new { displayName = match.displayName, summary = ctx, })
                .Dump();
```

I'm trying to create a list of names and some context for the search results if any exists. The output below is indicative of what *Dump()* displays and is the correct result:

```
displayName        summary 
----------------   ------------------------------------------
Sausage Roll       ...Email: Sausage.Roll@somewhere.com...
Hamburger Pattie
```

Edit: Regex version is below, definitely tidier:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\|((?:[^|]*)Sausage[^|]*)\|");      
var context = (from match in matches
                let m = reg.Match(match.summary)
                let ctx = m.Success ? string.Format("...{0}...", m.Groups[1].Value) : ""
                select new { displayName = match.displayName, context = ctx, })
                .Dump();
```

Comment: why not use regex to simplify this into 1-2 lines if you just want name and some context search? the linq expression is probably overkill

Comment: ok, i don't think i explained my answer well, even though u've already given me the tick, i'd feel horrible if i left u with that solution, check my updated answer.

Comment: and this is the **REAL** regex site i use http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm the other one was recommended by other SO users... i don't use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or something like this:

```
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"^|Email.*|$");
    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(match.displayName + " ..." + reg.Match(match.summary) + "... ");
    }
```

I haven't tested this, probably not even correct syntax but just to give you an idea of how you could do it with regex.

**Update**
Ok, i've seen your answer and it's good that you posted it because I think i didn't explain it clearly.
I expected your answer to look something like this at the end (tested using LINQPad now, and now i understand what you mean by using LINQPad because it actually does run a C# program not just linq commands, awesome!) Anyway this is what it should look like:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-20}...{1}...", match.displayName, Regex.Match(match.summary, @"Email:(.*)[|]").Groups[1]));
}
```

That's it, the whole thing, take linq out of it, completely!
I hope this clears it up, you do not need linq at all.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Yes I think a Regex solution is probably a better option. If you don't have LINQPad I highly recommend it for checking Stack Overflow answers before submitting them ;-)

Comment: @David, not sure what you're talking about, how is LINQPad going to help me check my regex expression? It might help your query statement but http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is what i use for checking my regex statements ;)

Comment: How rude, sending me to a flash site. LINQPad would have let you run your statements without having to wrap them in a unit test, program, or project. In the case of the code above, having identified/addressed the syntax errors, it would have produced `Sausage Roll ...... Hamburger Pattie ......`. Highly recommended tool, not just for testing queries but yes it does that as well.

Comment: But I *like* linq. I can see what you're suggesting but I think my original question was a bit hasty. The string I'm trying to match is the original search string the user entered that was used to get the array of matches. I want to extract from the summary string the substring between the bars that contains the matching search string. The result of the query is used in an ajax autocomplete text box to provide context for each suggestion. BTW, in in regex `(.*)` is greedy and would match as much of the string as possible, which is why I use a negated character class. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

(I know this doesn't answer your specific question), but here's my contribution anyway:

You haven't really described how your data comes in.  As @Joe suggested, you could use a regex or split the fields as I've done below.

Either way I would suggested refactoring your code to allow unit testing.

Otherwise if your data is invalid / corrupt whatever, you will get a runtime error in your linq query.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var matches = new[] 
        {
            new { displayName = "Sausage Roll", summary = "|Title: Network Coordinator|Location: Best Avoided|Department: Coordination|Email: Sausage.Roll@somewhere.com|" },
            new { displayName = "Hamburger Pattie",  summary = "|Title: Network Development Engineer|Location: |Department: Planning|Email: Hamburger.Pattie@somewhere.com|" },
        };

        IList<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        foreach (var m in matches)
        {
            string[] fields = m.summary.Split('|');
            persons.Add(new Person { displayName = m.displayName, Title = fields[1], Location = fields[2], Department = fields[3] });
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(2, persons.Count());
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        /* etc. */
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I've been playing with this in LINQPad so the advice to unit test might be considered by some to be not relevant. And yes I'm aware I could take a more procedural approach and I was originally using the split method in my expression but why go to the effort of splitting the string when I know the pattern I'm looking for. I will admit to writing my question just prior to leaving work so I will edit to try to provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
var context = (from match in matches
                let summary = match.summary
                let idx = summary.IndexOf("Sausage")
                let test=idx == -1 
                let start =test ? 0 : summary.LastIndexOf('|', idx) + 1
                let stop = test ? 0 : summary.IndexOf('|', idx)
                let ctx = test ? "" : string.Format("...{0}...", summary.Substring(start, stop - start))
                select new { displayName = match.displayName, summary = ctx, })
                .Dump();
```

Comment: @Christian, this part `let test=idx == -1 ` so you can just use `test` instead of `idx == -1`

Comment: I assumed the problem was that the test code was being duplicated, so this solves that problem.